# How to get pointer to an existing NSObject during runtime using its hash value

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, runtime

Assuming I have a hash value of some NSObject during runtime.

Is there a way to find a pointer to that object using just hash value?

I don't want to store pointers to objects and their hashes as keys. I imagine that iOS already doas that.

Comment: Hash values aren't guaranteed to be unique. That is, two objects may have the same hash. How would you deal with that?

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist not important in my case.

Comment: @Cyprian: Perhaps you can better explain what you are trying to do. And what do you mean by "iOS already does that"?

Comment: @MartinR was trying to find out if an object has some kind of unique id during its live in runtime. Would memory address be such an id?

Comment: Yes, the memory address is constant during the lifetime.

Comment: Which... is what the value in a pointer is telling you..., the memory address.

Comment: @nhgrif ye I realized that when I was typing! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way, not even an unreliable way, to do this.

Many objects have hashes in ways that makes it impossible to reference it. You will have duplicates because of this. One example, as @Martin said, is NSArrays. NSArrays' hashes are just the number of elements in the array.